# Batch file using icacls not executing

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-server-2012-r2, icacls

I'm reading the users from a file and I try to grant them access to a specific folder, but when I execute the batch file below nothing happens. Can someone please explain me what is wrong?

Edit: I'm using Windows Server 2012 R2.

This is the code within the file:

```
for /f %%i in (D:\Users\SBZ\DL_RO_SBZ_USERS.txt) do (
    icacls D:\Users\SBZ\%%i /grant %%i@domain.com:(OI)(CI)F /Q
)
pause
```

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Super User. This is a little vague. Please explain "*nothing happens*". Does that mean the batch file does not start, it gives an error, that specific `for` clause doesn't run, etc. If you are getting an error message, please quote it exactly as you see it.

Comment: It means that the batch file does not start so I can't see any error or a clause message.

Comment: How are you running the file?  Can you put an echo Hello World as the first line?

Comment: [Debugging your batch files](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_debugging.php)

Answer (score 0):

The parentheses in your Icacls statement is setting off the loop I think. Try:

```
for /f %%i in (D:\Users\SBZ\DL_RO_SBZ_USERS.txt) do (
    icacls D:\Users\SBZ\%%i /grant %%i@domain.com:(OI^)(CI^)F /Q
)
pause
```

The `^` “escapes” the parentheses.